# unable to toggle div from handlebar template

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I need to open up a div onclick. Click link is in handlebar template and the div which needs to be opened is in the page. Since the click-able link is loading from the js handlebar template **(bootstrap popover)**, it is not showing up the div on click.

How do I get it worked? Here is my handlebar template

```
<script id="template-rating" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="span6">
        <a href="#myReviewForm" id="scroll" class="btn">
            <i class="icon icon-star"></i> Write review
        </a>
    </div>
</script>
```

Here is the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wQe8K/1/)**

**P.S: handlebar template is loading in bootstrap popover.**

Comment: I think you missed  `$('.scroll').on('click',function());`? instead of `$('#scroll').on('click',function());`? using the ID attribute.

Comment: Sorry that was typing mistake. But evn then it wont work.

Comment: can you try using `$('#scroll').on('click',function(){})`? , I suspect delegated event here.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, this is working fine now,

```
    <div class="span6">
          <a href="#myReviewForm" id="scroll" class="btn"> Write review</a>
        </div>

<button class="write">write comment</button>
<form class="postbox" style="display:none">
    <textarea></textarea>
</form>
```

Fiddle[`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/wQe8K/3/)